# How can I get user fields to populate in Invoice and Memo when 'Reverse' and 'Reverse and Apply Memo' processes run

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have added a user field to the grid section of Invoice and Memo - and I'd like to bring the value of that field forward when the processes for 'reverse' or 'reverse and apply memo' are run.  I've looked at the source code and can't find a good way to use the override for either ReverseInvoice() or InsertReversedTransactionDetails().

Any thoughts on a clean way to do this - or is there a better method to override that would do the trick?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the InsertReversedTransactionDetails method as follows (and adding the necessary associated other methods):

[image]